# I am trying to access whatsapp status folder,but while running the app status folder is not showing

Tags: android, android-studio, android-developer-api

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65iE8.png)I am trying to access whatsapp status folder in android 11 using media store api. When I am running the app whatsapp folder is showing but status folder is not showing. Please help me

I have tried all the things but status folder is not showing.

Comment: I see nothing. No code. No folder. You posted your problem in the wrong way.

Comment: Welcome to SO ! Please avoid sharing your code as image.